# Copying row including formatting gives: "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using following subroutine to copy row including formatting from one worksheet to another:

```
Sub CpRowToSheetInclFormatting(rowNumber, srcWSheetName, dstWSheetName)
  '* SELECT SRC
  Worksheets(srcWSheetName).Activate
  Worksheets(srcWSheetName).Rows(rowNumber).Select

  '* COPY
  Selection.Copy

  '* SELECT DST
  Worksheets(dstWSheetName).Activate
  Worksheets(dstWSheetName).Rows(rowNumber).Select

  ' PASTE
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

This is working except one scenario (one that I've experienced maybe there are others). If there are merged cells in source worksheet then I get:

> This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized

How can I copy row from source to destination worksheet including formatting and ensure that merged cells will be merged also in destination worksheet?

Bonus question: Can those be combined into one command?:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: By avoiding merged cells at all cost.

Comment: @ExcelHero and is there a way how to check if row contains merged cells? If yes I could skip them and in destination worksheet print notification message instead of given row.

Comment: I will second Excel Hero's comment. However, since that may not be a solution, you might be able to use an On Error statement that goes and manually unmerges all cells regardless if they are merged or not, and then attempts to copy and paste again after the cells are unmerged.  This is a kind of ugly but that's why merged cells are a nightmare.

Comment: You can check a row for merged cells by using the following (checking row 12 in this example):   `MsgBox IsNull(Rows(12).MergeCells)`

Comment: @ExcelHero Thank you for that. One question that comes to my mind is: what happens if the cells are merged vertically? For example A12 with A11 ?

Comment: You run the test for each row you are interested in. In your example, both row 11 and row 12's text would return True.